# How can I split paragraphs into proper sentences in java using split()?

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split paragraphs into sentences. For eg: "Mary had a little lamb. Its fleece was white." i want to split it into:
"Mary had a little lamb."
"Its fleece was white."

currently i tried using text.split("[.]"); and got the result:
"Mary had a little lamb" (no full stop present. i need it)
" Its fleece was white" (space present before the sentence and still, no full stop)

what I intend to do is split this para into proper sentences and put it into array.

```
String text = sc.nextLine();
String[] sentence = text.split("[.]");
```

please help!

Comment: You should use a regular expression with a positive look behind for the period

Comment: You could split with a dot (`.`) character, trim the strings and then append the missing dot.

Comment: Can you say more about the application of this? If this is a programming assignment then the use of regular expressions will likely do the job but if this is a larger application and the input could be just any sentences then you should not try to write your own solution but should look at [natural language processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) libraries such as [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) that contain sentence splitters.

Comment: There are many problems you will run into with a home-brew solution in the real world such as the fact that there are different kinds of sentences (ok, you can write a regex that accommodates question marks etc.) but also uses of dots inside the sentence - see the etc. I just used.

Answer (score 1):

you can just append the full stop '.' to the string after the splitting.

Somthing like:

```
String[] splitString = theString.split("[.]");
for(String s : splitString){
    s += ".";
}
```

Something in that direction.

Comment: Thank you but it only solves a part of the problem. It takes care of the full stop at the end of each element of the array, i.e., every sentence. although after the first sentence, each sentence begins with a space. That space is causing trouble when further splitting some of these sentences into words using `split(" ")`. It takes into account the first space and prints it too.

Answer (score 0):

Somethig like this should work:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String paragraph = "Mary had a little lamb. Its fleece was white.";

        String sentences[] = paragraph.split("[.]");

        for (String sentence:sentences){
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I wanted a solution using `split()` as I haven't learned about `java.text.BreakIterator` yet. So if I have to explain my code, I won't be able to do it. If possible I would appreciate if you could help me using the `split()` method instead. thanks though

Comment: @EarthyCalf Oh ok, I understand. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is at least a chance that sentence splitting is not the last bit of natural language processing required, you should consider using a [natural language processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) library like [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/). You can try out OpenNLP through a web interface thanks to the [Gate project](https://gate.ac.uk/), who have made an [English language processing pipeline available as a web page](https://cloud.gate.ac.uk/shopfront/displayItem/opennlp-english-pipeline). Make sure to use the "Customise Annotations" button to get to see the sentence structure.

Answer (score -1):

assume this sentence:

```
String sResult = "This is a test. This is a T.L.A. test.";
```

so you'd better to try this

```
String sResult = "This is a test. This is a T.L.A. test.";
String[] sSentence = sResult.split("(?<=[a-z])\\.\\s+");
```

Result:

```
This is a test
This is a T.L.A. test.
```

Note that there are abbrevations that do not end with capital letters, such as abbrev., Mr., etc... And there are also sentences that don't end in periods!

Comment: This works almost perfectly, though is there a way to include the full stop at the end of the first sentence. I tried it with multiple sentences and only the last sentence has a full stop.